# AJAX implementation with drop down

Tags: java, ajax

HI

Currently into my application I perform a normal action for every drop down. For instance I have a page which has 5 drop down so it takes time for every consecutive action. So I am thinking to incorporate AJAX methodology for achieving it. Pls help me in doing so with an example.

Regards
Rj`

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want to do, and it may help if you show where you are trying to do something.  For example, do you want to do some action every time the selected item in the dropdown changes?

Comment: yes it is my requirement. Just putting it a bit simple.
Every time a user selects an option in the dropdown an action should be performed. The next dropdown should have values depending on 1st dropdown selection.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/sadtA/

This fills in the second drop-down with data from the server based on the selection in the first drop-down. There are comments to explain some of the jsFiddle specifics.